# Tricky complex contour integration

Tags: complex-analysis

Show that $$\int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{\cos^2{(\theta)}}{13-5\cos{(2\theta)}} \; d\theta = \frac{\pi}{10}$$ using complex contour integration.
I let $z = e^{i\theta}$ which means $dz = ie^{i\theta} \; d\theta = iz \; d\theta$ (meaning we know integrate over the unit circle $C$). Hence,
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{\cos^2{(\theta)}}{13-5\cos{(2\theta)}} \; d\theta = \oint_{C} \frac{1/4\left(z+1/z\right)^2}{13-5/2\left(z^2+1/z^2\right)} \; \frac{dz}{iz} = -\frac{i}{2}\oint_{C}\frac{z(z^2+1)^2}{(z^3-5)(5z^3-1)} \; dz.$$

Not sure what to do next. Is it to find the poles that are in the unit circle? Thanks!!!

Comment: How do you get the cubes in the denominator?

Comment: I'd start
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\cos^2\theta}{13-5\cos2\theta}\,d\theta
=\frac12\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{1+\cos2\theta}{13-5\cos2\theta}\,d\theta
=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1+\cos\phi}{13-5\cos\phi}\,d\phi=\cdots.
$$

Comment: Did you use a change of variables to get the $\phi$’s?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the last step, you should have

$$I=\frac i2\oint_C\frac{(z^2+1)^2}{\color{red}z(z^{\color{red}2}-5)(5z^{\color{red}2}-1)}~\mathrm dz$$

Now use the two roots in the unit circle from $5z^2-1=0\Rightarrow z=\pm\sqrt5/5$ and $z=0$, which are first order poles, to get

$$I=\frac\pi{10}$$

Comment: Don't think that substitution's quite correct either. I ended up with $z(5z^4-26z^2+5)$ as the denominator.

Comment: Oh nevermind. I'm stupid. That's the same denominator.